# Xslt url condition

Tags: xslt

I want to know if there's any url logic if url contains /market/3. like:

```
<xsl:variable name="cultureRequest" select="concat('http://',MAIN_URL)"  />
<xsl:if test="contains($cultureRequest, '/market/3')" >
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: What logic are you hinting at? How is `$url_HTTP_HOST` defined?

Comment: well, for example the main url

Comment: This is possible in XSLT, but why would you call it "url logic" and not "string logic"? `concat` concatenates two strings, and `contains` test whether one string is contained in another. Do you mean retrieving HTML from the web?

Comment: like in php can take the url of the site, so I'm wondering if in xslt has that kind of logic too like, if url contains /market/3/

Comment: PHP can take the URL of the site and.. do what? Now, you edited the question and the URL seems to be inside the XML element `MAIN_URL`. Can you show the input XML?

Comment: well, there's any way to check if url contains /market/3/ for example?

Answer (score 0):

> well, there's any way to check if url contains /market/3/ for example?

As I said in the comments, yes, that's possible. As long as the URL is a *string*. But you have to be aware that this does *not* mean that XSLT treats this string as an URL. It still thinks of it as a string.

For example, your code snippet works with the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MAIN_URL>www.main-url.com/market/3/xs.htm</MAIN_URL>
```

Then, you could apply a stylesheet like the one below. It outputs a `yes` element if the `contains` function returns true.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="cultureRequest" select="concat('http://',MAIN_URL)"  />
      <xsl:if test="contains($cultureRequest, '/market/3')" >
        <yes>!</yes>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

The URL contains `/market/3`, so the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<yes>!</yes>
```

Note: There are two things I did not understand about your question and that I tried to ask about in the comments:

- I am not sure why you concatenate the URL to `http;//` before handing
  it to `contains`.
- Why do you refer to "url logic"?